# Node 0.12.0 + Marklogic 8

Tags: marklogic

When I went to install the node module, I got this:

```
npm WARN engine marklogic@1.0.1: wanted: {"node":">=0.10.26 <0.11"}
  (current: {"node":"0.12.0","npm":"2.5.1"})
```

Should I be concerned or is this just a "ships passing in the night" issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Node.js 12.0 release came out the day after the MarkLogic Node.js API 1.0.1 release -- less than two weeks ago.

The  Node.js 12.0 release and the io.js 1.2.0 fork are likely to be shaking out initial bugs (and there are rumours the projects might merge, which sounds good but could destabilize).

We do plan to test on the new releases:

https://github.com/marklogic/node-client-api/issues/132

In the meantime, if you thrive on the cutting edge, you can disregard the warning and see how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

The guide at https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/node-dev/intro#id_64936 agrees with that npm warning: "Node.js, version in the range >= 0.10.26 <0.11". [Node 0.12 made some API changes](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/API-changes-between-v0.10-and-v0.12). I don't know that any of those will cause problems, but it's a possibility.

If you need support from MarkLogic, the first question will be "can you reproduce that with a supported version?" That's probably not so important for development, but I'd be cautious about deploying. Try not to depend on any v0.12 features, so that you can downgrade if necessary.